# Can't install psycopg2 on Windows to use pgloader

Tags: python, windows, postgresql, pip, psycopg2

I need to upload content of *csv* file to *PostgreSQL*. Content isn't perfect and contains mistakes, so I can't just use *COPY* command, I need to skip broken lines.

So I decided to use *[pgloader-2.3.2](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgloader/)*

I have *Win8 x64*, *Python 2.7.6 x64*, *pip 1.5.6*.

Pgloader requires *psycopg2* which I installed like described [here](https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win64-py27#egg=psycopg2
```

Now I see it in the list:

```
C:\dev\tools\pgloader-2.3.2>pip list
pip (1.5.6)
psycopg2 (2.5.2)
setuptools (3.6)
```

But my Python doesn't see it:

```
>>> import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
>>> 
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\dev\\tools\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\dev\\tools\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\dev\\tools\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\dev\\tools\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\dev\\tools\\Python27', 'C:\\dev\\tools\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
```

I went to `C:\dev\tools\Python27\Lib\site-packages\` directory and found there only `psycopg2-2.5.2-py2.7.egg-info` directory (there are no `psycopg2` or something similar).

How to solve this issue? I'm already spent about a day to solve a bunch of issues and now this one... It's really frustrating, that such primitive task requires so much efforts.

Comment: http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/

Comment: Install `psycopg2` from binaries on Windows.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that psycopg2 available as a binary file.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried installing psycopg2 on Windows using the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows), but had a similar issue because I've chosen the wrong version (32 bits instead of 64 bits). PIP told me that psycopg2 was installed successfully, but trying to run I've received the same message:

> ImportError: No module named psycopg2

Unistalled and tried again, with the correct version, and I got the warning:

> pip can't proceed with requirement 'psycopg2 from
>   git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win32-py34' due to
>   a pre-existing build directory.  location:
>   C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip_build_Administrator\psycopg2
>   This is likely due to a previous installation that failed. pip is
>   being responsible and not assuming it can delete this. Please delete
>   it and try again.

After cleaning the folder **C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip_build_my_username** and trying again, I've managed to install it correctly.

---

As pointed in comments, another way would be installing the binaries using: http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/